Process Flux with synchronous operators and the need of using limitRate
Using Reactor in Java, I am wondering why to use the "limitRate(int prefetchRate)" method in order to apply backpressure for the subscribers. If I am not wrong, in the next code(just an example),  the emission of the elements is sequential because I am using synchronous processing(not using flatMap,etc...) for each element meaning that until the execution of complexMathCalculation method on a number emitted is finished, the next number will not be emitted for processing. So, with this premise, I will be sure that numbers will be processed one by one and I wont be overwhelmed because everything is sequential.

Why do I need then to use here the limitRate method?:

Flux.range(1,1000)
   .map(number -> complexMathCalculation(number))
    .subscribe();


I assume with the previous premise, limitRate is not useful when you have sequential processing and is useful just for parallel processing and just to limit the number of items you can have at the same time being processed in the pipelines. Is this correct?

Thanks.
